# Firebase database 'set' method throwing error on runtime

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks, expo

I'm trying to run the above function on my react native project but am getting
"ERROR  ReferenceError: Property 'e' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes"
On running it what could possible be the error?

```
const saveCompletedProgress = (exercise_id) => {
    onValue(
      datRef,
      (snapshot) => {
        const res = snapshot?.val();
        if (res) {
          const exerciseDetails = res?.progress[week][day]?.completed ?? [];
          const setDetails = res?.progress[week][day]?.sets ?? [];
          const restWeeks = res?.progress;
          const restDays = res?.progress[week];
          set(datRef, {
            progress: {
              ...restWeeks,
              [week]: {
                ...restDays,
                [day]: {
                  completed: [...new Set([exercise_id, ...exerciseDetails])],
                  sets: setDetails,
                },
              },
            },
            image: data?.image,
          });
        } else {
          set(datRef, {
            progress: {
              [week]: {
                [day]: {
                  completed: [exercise_id],
                  sets: [],
                },
              },
            },
            image: data?.image,
          });
        }
      }
    );
  };
```

I was expecting the database to be updated with the entered value.

Comment: You have two calls to `set` and lots of other variables being used here.  I suggest boiling this down to the minimal example that reproduces the problem, narrowing in on the specific line of code that causes the problem.  I suggest first being able to use `set` without any variables, then add them in slowly until you figure out which one is at fault.

Comment: This worked thanks